# Not understanding why this function that takes two dimensional arrays doesnt work

Tags: c, arrays

Ok- ive managed to create a function that inputs a two dimensional array of 5 items that you can choose from, prints the items and then asks you for which you would like, and then takes that item you chose and places it into a reciept which is another 2d array that i defined globally in main. here is an MCVE:

```
char receipt[20][200];

void choose(char arr[5][200]){
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
  }

  printf("Enter in your choice");
  int choice;
  scanf("%d",&choice);

  printf("Choice test code:%s\n",arr[choice-1]);

  strcpy(receipt[0],arr[choice-1]);  

  printf("receipt[0]:%s\n",receipt[0]);

}
```

In my bigger program its in a loop so that i can go through the process multiple times and have different choices that i picked inside the receipt. Inside of main i can call receipt[x] and it works properly.I used a variable arrnum to keep track of how many items are inside the receipt and where to place the next one. But inside the function i created to print a receipt for some reason arrnum resets to 0. Here is the function for printing the receipt:

```
void printreceipt(){
    int qnum=0;
  printf("Inside of receipt function\n");
  printf("arrnum=%d\n",arrnum);
  printf("receipt[%d]:%s",arrnum,receipt[0]);
    printf("Receipt:\n");
    int itmnum=0;
    while(qnum<arrnum){
        printf("Item %d:\n%s",itmnum,receipt[qnum]);
        itmnum++;
        qnum++;
    }

}
```

Comment: What did you input for `choice`?

Comment: Why are you incrementing then decrementing `choice`? What is `arrnum`?

Comment: I editted the question to answer these comments, how do i reply to comments lol

Comment: You can simply write `printf("Choice test code:%s\n",arr[choice-1]);`

Comment: The biggest problem is that you cannot pass an array directly into a C function. You need to change the function signature to `void choose(char **arr, unsigned int dim1, unsigned int dim2)` and call it with `choose(arr, 5, 200)`.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you posted a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @enp While it's true that you can't pass an array directly to a C function, the notation OP is using is nonetheless a valid notation equivalent to `char (*)[200]`, which is a pointer to an array of 200 `char`. Your declaration, however, is not equivalent and will produce a warning when used.

Comment: Ive tried using void choose(char (*arr)[200]) but i get the same issue. I understand what you are saying but dont understand how i would implement the dimensions into **arr

Comment: @confusedbeginnerp What enp is trying to get at is that you can't pass arrays in C (which you probably already know, by the looks of things); if you try, you'll always be passing a pointer... and this can be proven by checking the value that `sizeof` returns. This is all probably irrelevant to your actual problem, though. I support the motion to produce an MCVE.

Comment: Working on a MCVE right now

Comment: So i created my best shot at an MCVE...... and it functions properly while my original code does not. This is frustrating

Comment: @confusedbeginnerp So the problem is in a piece of code you have not shown us. This is not just frustrating for you... How many people do you think would have seen this question and moved onto the next simply because you haven't made it easy (or possible) to reproduce your problem? Please think **carefully** about this next time you ask a question.

Comment: hmmm, what's the problem? The code seems to compile and work on my machine?

Comment: ^--- Case in point. People will move on because of this.

Comment: Your mcve works but the actual code doesn't? Have you checked the difference in initializing `arr`? Maybe the answer is somewhere in there.

Comment: I'm voting to close using the reason "Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce* it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." Hintedy hint.

Comment: The MCVE isn't complete; `printf` is undeclared

Comment: if `#include <stdio.h>` is added at the top, and the input is exactly `3` (and Enter), then the MCVE looks correct to me and runs correctly.  Please verify that running your actual MCVE gives you the problem.   It would be good to update the program to abort if `choice` is not in the range 1-5 .

Comment: In your original code you are copying from `arr` to `receipt` using `arrnum` as your index to `receipt`. Have you verified that the value of `arrnum` is correct during the run? Here's a suggestion. While no one can help you without seeing a reproducible small code, debugger is your best buddy in resolving this issue.

Comment: im sorry if i upset anyone, i am fairly new to this and so i re wrote the question and tried to make it more coherent. Sorry for any trouble.

Comment: No worries on my end. Coding's hard! But yeah, it's easier to get help the more clear and succinct your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Comment thread was so long it was making me nauseous. This code plus an unedited version of your choose function seems to work for me. Checked with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and no errors either, so I have no clue what's wrong with your setup.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int arrnum = 0;            // <------- did you do this? seems obvious...

void printreceipt() {
  for(int i = 0 ; i < arrnum; i++)
    printf("receipt[%d]: '%s'\n",i,receipt[i]);
}

int main(){
    char strings[5][200]=    {"string1","string2","string3","string4","string5"};
    while(arrnum<5) {
      choose(strings);
    }
    return 0;

}
```